# Why are some JavaScript constructors not functions?

Tags: javascript, constructor

Clarification:
"JavaScript constructor" should be more properly be written as "javascript constructor" to emphasize that the constructors considered are not just the native JavaScript language constructors, such as Object, Array, Function, etc. but also others, extrinsic to the JavaScript language definition but intrinsic to a browser, such as `XMLHttpRequest`, The word "JavaScript" is meant to indicate these constructors are expressed and accessed using JavaScript.

some references:

- Using a Constructor Function in [Working with Objects - MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_a_Constructor_Function)
- "`constructor`
  Specifies the function that creates an object's prototype"
  in [Object - MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Properties_2)
- an example: "... calling the `Worker()` constructor ..."
  [Worker - MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Worker)
- [What are the predefined primitive constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961019/what-are-the-predefined-primitive-constructors)
- [Where are constructors such as, `new Image()` and `new Option()`, documented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936071/where-are-constructors-such-as-new-image-and-new-option-documented)
- [Where is the Documentation for all of the Javascript HTML Element Constructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424571/where-is-the-documentation-for-all-of-the-javascript-html-element-constructors)

Rhetorically, there are references to constructor *functions* but NOT constructor *objects*!

(Facetiously, this is because Objects ARE functions, and Functions are objects!
[Why in JavaScript is a function considered both a constructor and an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372202/why-in-javascript-is-a-function-considered-both-a-constructor-and-an-object)
More specifically, objects, or is that obj-eggs?, ARE, ignoring literal instances, instantiations of functions and functions are Object instances of Functions. It is arguable that functions are fundamental to the existence of objects as evidenced by the fact
7. [Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)
       precedes
8. [Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)
in the MDN docs [JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide). That section 8, I object!, provides the details needed to create objects using constructors and function instantiations!)

Why are constructors that interface the DOM not functions?

```
javascript:
  alert([
    "using browser environment:  \n"+window.navigator.userAgent,
     Option, Image, Audio,
       Storage, XMLHttpRequest, Worker, FileReader,
   ] . join("\n\n"));
```

shows us:

> using browser environment:
>   Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US;
>   rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100423 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.3
>
> [object Option]
>
> [object Image]
>
> [object Audio]
>
> [object Storage]
>
> [object XMLHttpRequest]
>
> [object Worker]
>
> [object FileReader]

but ...

```
javascript:
  alert([
             XPCNativeWrapper,
  ].join("\n\n"));
```

(which produces

> function XPCNativeWrapper() {
>       [native code] }

)

and JavaScript language [constructors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects#Constructors) ARE functions.

```
javascript:
  alert([
    "using browser environment:  \n"+window.navigator.userAgent,
             Array, Boolean, Date, Function,
               Number, Object, RegExp, String,
                 Error, Iterator,
  ].join("\n\n"));
```

gives us:

> using browser environment:
>   Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US;
>   rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100423 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.3
>
> function Array() {
>       [native code] }
>
> function Boolean() {
>       [native code] }
>
> function Date() {
>       [native code] }
>
> function Function() {
>       [native code] }
>
> function Number() {
>       [native code] }
>
> function Object() {
>       [native code] }
>
> function RegExp() {
>       [native code] }
>
> function String() {
>       [native code] }
>
> function Error() {
>       [native code] }
>
> function Iterator() {
>       [native code] }

Comment: `function Object() { [native code] }` Clearly Object is a function.

(my tongue is in my cheek and I am being cheeky but ,,,)

Comment: Here are some Object objects that ARE functions:

`javascript:x=y=z=Object; alert([x,y,z].join("\n\n"))`

reiterating, every Object is a function! (not so every object!)

Answer (score 3):

First:

> Objects ARE functions

No, the are not:

```
> a = function() {}
  function () {}
> a instanceof Object
  true
> b = {}
  Object
> b instanceof Function
  false
```

---

The `toString` method (which is what gets called when you do string concatenation) is not a reliable way to get information about an object. If I use `typeof`, I get the following:

```
using browser environment:  
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:5.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0.1

function

function

function

object

function

function

function
```

So you see, most of them, apart form `Storage`, *are* actually functions (why it does not work for `Storage`, I don't know).

Also keep in mind that the DOM interface can behave differently than native JavaScript objects.

On the other hand, in **Chrome** the `toString` method gives this:

```
[object Function] 

[object Function] 

[object Function] 

function Storage() { [native code] } 

function XMLHttpRequest() { [native code] } 

function Worker() { [native code] } 

function FileReader() { [native code] }
```

Comment: `typeof Storage === "function"` in chrome12

Comment: The statement "Objects are functions!" was qualified as facetious - but ... Objects ARE Function instantiations! Without functions there are no instantiations, and without instantiations, via `new`, there are no objects! (except for literals such as `{property1:value1, property2:value2}` and predefined entities)

Comment: @ekim: Whether all objects are function instantiations is a difficult topic. You could say that everything is eventually created through the `Object` constructor function and inherits from `Object.prototype`. But what does the `Object` function inherit from? From `Function.prototype` which itself inherits from `Object.prototype` again. But `Object.prototype` does not inherit from any other object.

Comment: @ekim: If you want to have a better insight, I suggest you read the ECMAScript specification: http://ecma262-5.com/

Comment: also ... There is a distinction between an object (lower case) instance of arbitrary type, and an Object (capitalized), the constructor for an Object type which IS a function!

Comment: The circularity of obj-egg and functional form is self-consistent being neither ambiguous nor contradictory. [Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) explicitly states that constructors are used to create objects and that in fact in early JavaScript versions (1.1) this was the ONLY way!

Comment: @FelixKling let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2245/discussion-between-ekim-and-felix-kling)

Answer (score 2):

When you alert those values the browser engine is alerting `value.toString()` so we are talking about why does `Function.prototype.toString` behave in a strange manner.

The ES5.1 specification states :

> 15.3.4.2 Function.prototype.toString ( )
>   An implementation-dependent representation of the function is returned. This representation has the  syntax of a FunctionDeclaration.
>
> Note in particular that the use and placement of white space, line terminators, and 
>   semicolons within the representation String is implementation-dependent.
>
> The  toString function is not generic; it throws a  TypeError exception if its  this value is not a Function object. Therefore, it cannot be transferred to other kinds of objects for use as a method.

Clearly ES5 states that `toString` returns an implementation specific string.

If you read the [ES Harmony proposals](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3aproposals) page it states :

> function to string – greater specification for problematic Function.prototype.toString (markm, allen)

Here are some more resources :

- [ES:Harmony proposal for `Function.prototype.toString`](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3afunction_to_string)
- [ES:Harmonye strawman proposal for `Function.prototype.toString`](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman%3afunction_to_string)
- [ES-discuss mail archive about `Function.prototype.toString`](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es5-discuss/2009-May/002532.html)

Basically it's a known issue that `toString` on function objects (and especially host objects that are also functions) is undefined behaviour. The TC39 committee is already working on standardizing this.

As you can see the host objects are proposed to be standardized in strawman so it's in the air whether that makes it into ES6. However function objects living in ECMA land should have a standardized `toString` method in ES6 as defined on the harmony proposals page.

Comment: "15.3.4.2 Function.prototype.toString ( ) An implementation-dependent representation ... has the syntax of a FunctionDeclaration. "

Chrome's `function Worker() { [native code] }` qualifies but `[object Worker]` does not.

Comment: so ... Why don't `Image`, `Option` etc. conform? Why are they "known issues"?

Comment: @ekim again please distinquish between Host objects (part of the browser and DOM) and ES objects. Host objects can do whatever they please because they are host objects. They are as non-standard as you can get.

Comment: This is off topic but ...

Predefined objects are conventional and de facto standardized, such as JavaScript:
(quoting https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference#Global_Objects)

"Global Objects
Standard global objects (by category)"

though to be sure browsers from different vendors may "warp" the definitions and occasionally augment the "standard" repertoire.

The original question does not ask about "host objects" per se but '"JavaScript" constructors' (which are objects of type Function) only.

Comment: The original problem examples do distinguish between the origination of the constructors, whether DOM or native JavaScript, with their string representations that implies the constructor types may sometimes be generic Object and not Function. Why should this be?

Comment: @ekim yes but `Image` is a host object not a "JavaScript" constructor. And constructors are always functions. Don't trust `toString`. check `typeof Image`. As mentioned `Function.prototype.toString` is a mess

Comment: so ... since `Image` is NOT a constructor then how can it be used as one? ie. `new Image()`

Comment: The real issue is why the DOM interface does not subsume the conventions of JavaScript. `Image` is a function and is used as a constructor and so ... (rhetorically), why is it unconventional? ... because someone "goofed". Is `myFunc(){this.prop=2}` a "JavaScript" constructor? a javascript constructor? a constructor?

Comment: @ekim Because browser compliance sucks. No-one obheres to standards, everyone does what they wants.

Comment: which is why we cannot NOT use stackoverflow.com reliably in any browser! ... there is profound compliance ... and standards do exist for much more than a modest modicum of web page manuscripts

Comment: @ekim sorry _what_ is the standard for the fucntion objects in the DOM? _WHERE_ does it say in the _STANDARDS_ how host constructor objects should behave? **WHY ARE YOU COMPLAINING ABOUT UNDEFINED BEHAVIOUR BEING UNDEFINED!**

Comment: r u sure it's undefined? r u sure a complaint is being made? "Why" is a simple question and not a "browser compliance sucks" euphemism. Certainly the examples observed in the original question above ARE defined in the formalities of the programming that implements the browser.

Comment: There is no emotional attachment, other than mere curiosity, in pursuing the question of "How or why does (or not) a formal language, ie programmed, program such as a browser realize or contravene the natural language descriptions documenting the same?"

Comment: Determining whether or not there is any compliance, consistency and conformity or indeed, if any association is completely absent and undefined, may require serious effort. The Web IDL http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/WebIDL/#idl-objects for instance distinguishes "each object ...  is ... either a platform object or a user object" but has no references to "host object", which presumably identifies with "platform object", or "host constructor object".

Answer (score 1):

The question might actually be paraphrased as:

"Do JavaScript (ECMAScript) language conventions apply to and qualify other components of the browser such as the programming objects that interface the DOM?"

The original question uses objects that are supposedly of type Function and used as constructors. The examples shows a dichotomy exists with the programming environment and the DOM interface in how they are represented.

If there is this actual dichotomy, is it made explicit?

This may be the actual issue. If so, the original question should be preceded by this to direct attention to the real problem.

references:

- [W3C HTML 5 specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/)
- [W3C WebIDL interface definition language specification](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/WebIDL/)
- [W3C DOM](http://www.w3.org/DOM/)
- [Mozilla JavaScript technologies overview](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/the_dom_and_javascript)
- [Mozilla DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM)
- [Mozilla ECMAScript references](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Language_Resources)
- [ecma262-5.com](http://ecma262-5.com/)

[ECMAScript](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Sections_TOC.htm) language `constructor` details:

- [4.3.4 constructor](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_4.htm#Section_4.3.4)
- [13.2.2   [[Construct]]](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_13.htm#Section_13.2.2)
- [15.3.4.5.2 [[Construct]]](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_15.htm#Section_15.3.4.5.2).
- "every built-in constructor has the Function prototype object"
  quoting section [15   Standard Built-in ECMAScript Objects](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_15.htm#Section_15)
- "it is expected that the computational environment of an ECMAScript program will provide ... certain environment-specific host objects, whose description and behaviour are beyond the scope of this specification"
  quoting section [4   Overview](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_Section_4.htm)