# If Functions are objects in javascript, why the function.constructor points to Function instead of Object?

Tags: javascript

When creating the following function from the window object like this,

```
         function userInfo() {};
```

how come the userInfo.constructor displays Function instead of Object since functions are objects?

It even display Function instead of Object when using the following,

```
         Function.constructor
```

Comment: Arrays are objects with the Array constructor. Date instances are objects with the Date constructor. Something can be an object and not be constructed by the Object constructor.

Comment: `Function`s are objects, not `Object`s.

Comment: See also [this overview](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7018023/1048572)

Comment: why does `new userInfo.prototype.constructor()` creates object but `new userInfo.constructor()` doesn't ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`userInfo.constructor` is `Function` because:

1. `userInfo` has no own `constructor` property.
2. The value of `userInfo`'s [[Prototype]] internal slot is `Function.prototype`.
3. `Function.prototype` has an own `constructor` property, whose value is `Function`.

`Function.constructor` is `Function` too because of the same reason:

1. `Function` has no own `constructor` property.
2. The value of `Function`'s [[Prototype]] internal slot is `Function.prototype`.
3. `Function.prototype` has an own `constructor` property, whose value is `Function`.

That is, `Function` instances (like `userInfo` or `Function` itself) inherit a `constructor` property from `Function.prototype`, which can be used to know they are instances of `Function`.

Answer (score 0):

Functions are high level object. Actually, function is an object. That's why you can assign your functions any values like `userInfo.anotherFunction = function() { return 'something'};` and then call `userInfo.anotherFunction();`. That's why you have both

```
var obj = {};
function myFunc() {}

console.log(obj.constructor)
console.log(myFunc.constructor)
```

These both will print functions as constructors. 
Simply, if every object has `.constructor` property, and any function in javascript is itself object you surely will have `.constructor` property on any function.

Also Function is a constructor of any function. Any constructor is a function that's why Function also has .constructor property

Check this link http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#16

Comment: Correction, obj.constructor prints out // Object

Comment: hm.. http://jsbin.com/namuyurime/edit?js,console check this, here hello.constructor is a function

Answer (score 0):

The constructor property value of any object is inherited from its prototype object's `constructor` property value.

The prototype of an object is set to the `prototype` property value of the function (object) used to construct it, at the time it was created.

Because function objects are created using the global `Function` constructor function, they inherit `Function` as their `constructor` property:

```
 function Foo(){};  // Foo is constructed by global object "Function".
 Foo.constructor;   // Function, inherited from Function.prototype.constructor property
```

Note the prototype object of `Function` is set to `Function.prototype` in native code:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(Function) === Function.prototype // is true.
```

This has the effect that any properties added to Function.prototype are inherited by Function. This is desirable because `Function` is, of course, a function. As an implicit **side effect** however it also results in native code `Function` being returned as the constructor of itself.

Also:

- `Function.prototype` is an instance of Object so function objects inherit from Object.prototype as well.
- Use of the "constructor" property in code has no guarantee of safety. While the `prototype` property and its `constructor` property may not be changed for `Function`, neither is write protected for function objects in general.