# where does `MyFunc.constructor` is pointing to and what is its uses

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor, prototype

I'm currently studying javascript prototype and inheritance (man, it is confusing, but soldiering on)

```
function MyFunc(){}
```

I have noticed that there is a `constructor` property on both `MyFunc` and `MyFunc.prototype`

[image]

I know that `MyFunc.prototype.constructor` is pointing back to `MyFunc`, but I'm not exactly sure where `Myfunc.constructor` is pointing to?

So where does `MyFunc.constructor` is pointing to and what is its uses?

Comment: An object’s `constructor` property should point to its… constructor. `MyFunc` is a function, so its constructor is `Function`.

Comment: The introductory statements of [`Function` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) may clarify.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but I guess all function objects have its `constructor` property set to `Function`?

Comment: That's correct, but the use of the `Function` constructor is generally discouraged, for the same reasons that [`eval` is discouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/q/86513/5743988).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35709103/if-functions-are-objects-in-javascript-why-the-function-constructor-points-to-f

Comment: “correct me if I'm wrong, but I guess all function objects have its `constructor` property set to `Function`?” Yes, unless you change it. (It’s a writable property.)

Comment: Like all objects, Functions inherit from their internal `[[Prototype]]`, so function objects inherit the constructor property from [*Function.prototype*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-function.prototype). They do not have their own *constructor* property (though you can add one).